# Creating xml with xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want create xml file of this structure:

```
 <Devices>
   <Device Number="58" Name="Default Device" >
     <Functions>
         <Function Number="1" Name="Default func" />
         <Function Number="2" Name="Default func2" />
         <Function Number="..." Name="...." />
     </Functions>
   </Device>
 </Devices>
```

Here's my code:

```
document.Element("Devices").Add(
new XElement("Device",
new XAttribute("Number", ID),
new XAttribute("Name", Name),
new XElement("Functions")));
```

Each object "device" have List<> of "functions", how can i add "functions" to xml???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Each object "device" have List<> of "functions", how can i add "functions" to xml???

Really easily - LINQ to XML makes this a doddle:

```
document.Element("Devices").Add(
    new XElement("Device",
       new XAttribute("Number", ID),
       new XAttribute("Name", Name),
       new XElement("Functions",
           functions.Select(f => 
               new XElement("Function",
                   new XAttribute("Number", f.ID),
                   new XAttribute("Name", f.Name))))));
```

In other words, you just project your `List<Function>` to an `IEnumerable<XElement>` using `Select`, and the `XElement` constructor does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.Element("Devices").Add(
new XElement("Device",
new XAttribute("Number", ID),
new XAttribute("Name", Name),
new XElement("Functions", from f in functions select new XElement("Function", new XAttribute("Number", f.Number), new XAttribute("Name", f.Name)))));

functions would be your list of functions.
```